# How do I generate a pubxml file for Azure App Service like the Visual Studio 2015 UI?

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, msdeploy

I have a simple web application in **Visual Studio 2015**.

With the **Azure SDK** installed, when I right-click the project and select **Publish**, I get a UI that allows me to select **Microsoft Azure App Service** as a publish target.

If I sign in and walk through the wizard, I ultimately end up with **.pubxml** and **.pubxml.user** files in my project that have the user names passwords, deployment endpoint, etc. that I need.

I am looking for a way to do this from the command line (ideally with **PowerShell** cmdlets for Azure, but calls to **MSDeploy.exe** or **MSBuild.exe** would be just fine).

Answer (score 0):

Msbuild(Msdeploy) does not have related argument to create .pubxml and .pubxml.user, if want to use command line to achieve, you need to create a custom task, which create the xml by using code (C# or other). And you need to know the xml structure and related content.

About custom task, please refer to:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2006/01/21/how-to-implementing-custom-tasks-part-i/

About create xml via c#, please refer to：https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604982.aspx